# How to create podcast for Zune using youtube?

Tags: youtube, podcast, zune

I'm using Zune and I want to be able to add, as a podcast, all the videos from a youtube user.

But after trying several scripts/services (PHP, Yahoo! Pipes, etc.) it turns that the different podcast generators work fine but when I try to download a video there is an error.

Do you know any script (PHP, JavaSCript, c#, etc.) or any online service that can be used successfully with Zune?

Thanks in advance.

@+
rv.

Comment: You may find more useful help at http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.ytpodcaster.com

Enter the youtuber's username, click 'get feed', and you'll be presented with options for iTunes, Zune, Other, RSS.

Give it a shot and let me know how it works for you.

Comment: Hi,

Already tested, the generated feed url is returning a 404 error, for example:
http://www.ytpodcaster.com/users_videos/africa1video/22

Thanks anyway,

@+
rv.